# Change Calendar Created by

Tags: google-apps-script

When I execute `createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options)` to create a Calendar Event, how can I change the "Created by" to other Gmail user, not me?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not possible in the "normal" calendar interface isn't it ? I never heard of any API or hack that can do it.

In my opinion it would be an obvious privacy violation if it was.